# Load controllers in angular from different files instead just 1

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying load a controller from a diferrent js but I have no sucess, can you guys help me load this controller called StreetListCtrl.js on page?

UsersListCtrl load perfect just StreetListCtrl does not load/

my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='myApp' lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>angularjs</title>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src='public/javascripts/ng-controller.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
                <table ng-controller="UsersListCtrl">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Username</th>
                        <th>UserId</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr ng-repeat="user in users | orderBy:'id' ">
                        <td><strong>{{ user.name }}</strong></td>
                        <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                  <p>street list </p>

                 <table ng-controller="StreetListCtrl">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>street name</th>
                        <th>id</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr ng-repeat="data in street | orderBy:'id' ">
                        <td><strong>{{ data.name }}</strong></td>
                        <td>{{ data.id }}</td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

StreetListCtrl.js

```
angular.module('myApp')

myApp.controller('StreetListCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){
        $scope.street =[
        {name:'1 smithfield', id:3},
        {name:'2 river plate', id:1333},
        {name:'3 river plate', id:1}
    ];
}])
```

ng-controller.js:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('UsersListCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){
        $scope.users =[
        {name:'douglas', id:3},
        {name:'bruno', id:1}
    ];
}])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the second javascript file.  You have:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>angularjs</title>
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src='public/javascripts/ng-controller.js'></script>
</head>
```

It should be:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>angularjs</title>
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src='public/javascripts/ng-controller.js'></script>
  <script src='public/javascripts/StreetListCtrl.js'></script>
</head>
```

and StreetListCtrl.js should be:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('StreetListCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){
        $scope.street =[
        {name:'1 smithfield', id:3},
        {name:'2 river plate', id:1333},
        {name:'3 river plate', id:1}
    ];
}])
```

Comment: I would like load just 1 js file, will be possible? lets say i will have 1000 controllers, i need call all in my page?

Comment: It is possible, but for that you need to use a build system like, say, gulp, along with something to minify your javascript, like usemin with concat, uglify, etc.

Gulp.js:  http://gulpjs.com/
usemin plugin for gulp:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-usemin

These will compile your js down to one minified source file which will then be loaded, and replace your multiple script src tags with a single one after the build process.

Comment: I use grunt concat to minimize the js , but i still think i can use just 1 js file for that. :)

Comment: Think of it this way:  I create 3 separate files, A, B & C.  I explicitly tell A about B, but nowhere do I tell A about C.  How then, can I expect A to know that file C exists and has a controller that I want A to use?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `<script src='public/javascripts/StreetListCtrl.js'></script>`
from index.html

Comment: I would like load just 1 js file, will be possible? lets say i will have 1000 controllers, i need call all in my page?

Comment: If you want to use different js files then you should load all of them